# Dynamic memory allocation in c without malloc

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

Here's a C program one of my friends had written.
From what I know, arrays had to be initialised at compile time before C99 introduced VLA's, or using `malloc` during runtime.

But here the program accepts value of a `const` from the user and initialises the array accordingly.
It's working fine, even with `gcc -std=c89`, but looks very wrong to me.
Is it all compiler dependent?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
 int const n;
 scanf("%d", &n);
 printf("n is %d\n", n);
 int arr[n];
 int i;
 for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   arr[i] = i;
 for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
   printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I compile this as you've suggested, I see the warning `test.c:7: warning: writing into constant object (argument 2)`, indicating that the compiler is aware that this is not fine.

Comment: Of course, this means that the real problem here is you're trying to modify a `const` object.  So nothing to do with VLAs ;)

Comment: It's a GNU extension prior to C99, compile with `-pedantic`.

Comment: Yeah, I got the warning, but I was expecting that the compiler would just not compile the code for me and the program wouldn't work. Why is that some rules are implemented completely, and some mistakes are let off with a warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-pedantic` to your compile options (e.g, `-Wall -std=c89 -pedantic`) and `gcc` will tell you:

`warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘arr’`

which means that your program is indeed not c89/c90 compliant.

Change with `-pedantic` with `-pedantic-errors` and `gcc` will stop translation.

Comment: So if suppose I compiler as `gcc -std=89` still due to variable length array code compiled as c99 ? And if I use `gcc -std=89 -pedantic-errors` then compiler will behave as c89 and don't compile?

Comment: Yeah, it's like the compiler is making us choose how we want it to behave, and not follow the said standards completely. How should we ideally predict the behavior?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan regarding `-pedantic`, `gcc` documentation says *Valid ISO C and ISO C++ programs should compile properly with or without this option [...] However, without this option, certain GNU extensions and traditional C and C++ features are supported as well. With this option, they are rejected.*

Comment: So, is it safe to say that the program has undefined behavior as a C90 program, depending on the compiler used?

Comment: @Flipper It is safe to say the program is not a strictly conforming c90 program  (c90 6.5.4.2 constraint is violated).

Answer (score 1):

This called Variable Length Arrays and allowed in C99 . Compiling in `c89` mode with `-pedantic` flag, compiler will give you warnings

```
[Warning] writing into constant object (argument 2) [-Wformat]  
[Warning] ISO C90 forbids variable length array 'arr' [-Wvla]
[Warning] ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-pedantic]
```

Comment: Indeed, but the OP is asking about `-std=c89`.