# Structs and functions in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm having trouble assigning a passing a pointer of struct to a function my code (put simply) is

```
struct userCom{
    int x;
    int y;
}

main(void){
    struct userCom com;
    userComFunction(com);
    printf("%d", com.x);
}

userComFunction(struct userCom *return_type){
    struct userCom temp;
    temp.x = 10;
    printf("%d", temp.x);
    *return_type = temp;
}
```

It would print

```
10
11537460
```

Am I passing through the pointer wrong?
I cannot seem to figure out why com.x is not equal to 10

Comment: You need to pass the reference to the pointer through. Try 'userComFunction(&com)'

Comment: Try enabling all warnings when compiling (gcc -Wall, for example). This should point out the problem.

Comment: btw you are missing return types of functions. use `gcc -Wall` option.

Comment: `main(void)` should be `int main(void)`. `userComFunction(/* ... */)` should be `void userComFunction(/* ... */)`. When you call `userComFunction(com)`, the compiler doesn't know what arguments the function expects, because it hasn't seen a declaration for it. As of C99, the lack of a declaration is illegal (a constraint violation); in C90, the compiler will make incorrect assumptions about what `userComFunction` looks like. To fix both problems, either move the definition of `userComFunction` above `main`, or add a "forward" declaration: `void userComFunction(struct userCom *return_type);`.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, the problem is that you're passing the wrong type of argument to `userComFunction`. But the real problem is that your compiler isn't telling you that.

As of C90 (that's two standards ago), calling a function with no visible declaration was legal, and the compiler would make assumptions (often incorrect) about what the function actually looks like. When the compiler sees the call to `userComFunction`, it hasn't seen a declaration or definition for `userComFunction`, so it can't diagnose your error.

As of C99, calling a function with no visible declaration is a *constraint violation*, meaning that a compiler must at least warn you about it. C99 also dropped the "implicit `int`" rule, so you can no longer omit the return type in a function declaration; `main` should be declared with an `int` return type (*not* `void`!), and `userComFunction`, since it doesn't return anything, should be `void`.

You can either move the full definition of `userComFunction` above the definition of `main`, or you can leave the definition where it is and add a "forward" declaration:

```
void userComFunction(struct userCom *return_type);

int main(void) {
    /* ... */
}

void userComFunction(struct userCom *return_type) {
    /* ... */
}
```

When you do that, the compiler should let you know that your call:

```
userComFunction(com);
```

is incorrect. (The fix is to change `com` to `&com`.)

You should also use gcc's command-line options to enable more warnings. For example:

```
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
```

`-std=c99` says to enforce ISO C99 rules. `-pedantic` says to *really* enforce those rules. `-Wall` and `-Wextra` enable additional warnings.

Comment: I always wonder by reading your answer. You don't miss anything You should be teacher :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: (`-pedantic-errors` turns warnings enabled by `-pedantic` into fatal errors.) It depends. If you have a policy of treating all warnings as problems that need to be fixed, there's not much practical difference between `-pedantic` and `-pedantic-errors`. If you actually need to write non-portable code in some cases, and you really know what you're doing, `-pedantic` can warn you about potential problems, and you can decide for yourself whether to change the code accordingly. For beginning programmers trying to write portable code, `-pedantic-errors` is probably a good idea.

Comment: Now it is better clear to me, [I had doubt here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19208886/1673391) So I asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign 10 to x,then you should do it this way.
Here is the correct code-

```
struct userCom{
int x;
int y;
}
void struct userComFunction(struct userCom*);
main(void)
{
struct userCom com;
userComFunction(&com);
printf("%d\n", com.x);
}

userComFunction(struct userCom *return_type){
struct userCom temp;
temp.x = 10;
printf("%d\n", temp.x);
return_type->x= temp.x;
}
```